# python: Class derived from argparse module can't call its own derived class method

Tags: python, class, derived

I am no expert on python classes, but I've tested and searched and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. If I define a base class with methods I can call the class methods from within the class. If I override a base class method from the argparse module in a derived class I can't call my derived class methods.  I need to understand how to define a derived class method that can be called. I do not know if this is special to argparse or all derived classes. Here are two test classes:

```
class testA():
def usage(self):
    print "testing testA"

def __init__(self):
    self.usage()
```

In pdb I can do "dir(testA) and I see the "usage" method. I can also call it when instantiating class testA.

```
import subprocess
import argparse
import sys

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def usage(self):
        print "redispub.py -s 'started' -c 'ethandevelop-C1-G1' -m 'salt started' -e 'us-east-develop.onvamdev.com' -p 6379"
        print

    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
        self._usage()
        self.__usage()
        self.usage()
        sys.exit(2)
```

Note in the code above I call "usage" three different ways. The errors vary a bit in the 3 calls but none of them work. I tried each one alone, but above just put all of them so you can see what was tried. In pdb I can do "dir(MyParser)" and I also see "usage" as a method, but when I call it I get either "no attribute" or TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable":
-> self._usage()
AttributeError: "'MyParser' object has no attribute '_usage'"

> /data/onvu360/redispub.py(21)error()
>   -> self._usage()
>   (Pdb) n
>   --Return--
>   /data/onvu360/redispub.py(21)error()->None

-> self.usage()
(Pdb) n
TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable"

I am wondering if it is related to the fact that I'm overriding the base class "error" method and it can't see my derived class "usage" method?

*** EDIT based on my answer below ***
Here is the valid code that works with argparse:

```
import subprocess
import argparse
import sys

class MyParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def myusage(self):
        print "redispub.py -s 'started' -c 'ethandevelop-C1-G1' -m 'salt started' -e 'us-east-develop.onvamdev.com' -p 6379"
        print

    def error(self, message):
        sys.stderr.write('error: %s\n' % message)
        self.myusage()
        sys.exit(2)
```

*** Additional Update ***
The point was made below that you may not need to subclass ArgumentParser and in this case you can use their *usage* attribute to pass in the usage text. In my case I needed to override *error* so this was not an option.

Comment: Why are you trying to call `_usage` and `__usage` if your method's name is `usage`?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I suspect that if you look at the begins library - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/begins/0.9 - your question goes away. It documents your API for you from the doc strings. I'm guessing you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: BrenBarn if you read my notes I already explain, "Note in the code above I call 'usage' three different ways." The reason is because there are some built-in method formats where special characters are auto-prepended. I state that I'm not an expert on python classes and this is a series of tests to understand why method calling doesn't work in a certain situation. So there are good reasons to try different ways of 'descrambling' the names. It is all a test.

Comment: @SteveJ I thank you for the link, but I don't see how this will help. I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, I'm trying to understand derived classes and method calling in python. I get that no one so far knows the answer to my question, but I'm less clear on why I'm being directed to places that are not going to answer the question. If this was basic python then someone could answer it. All the details are given. The first test class works as expected. The argparse class does not, and so far there is no one who knows why. I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: @tradetree -- My comment was in reference to your printing the usage instructions. My guess was that you were trying to make a nicer interface to argparse. Since "begins" already does much of that for you - I thought it likely you don't need to extend argparse at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the base class, in this case "argparse" was defining a "usage" method and it could not be overridden. If I step into the argparse module code, prog is set to the argv[0] value containing the program name and usage is set to "None". When "error" method called self.usage() it was calling the base class "None" value for usage and giving the error. I was able to fix this by changing my method to "myusage" and it was as simple as that. I never dreamed it was a name conflict with the base class!

I found "dir(object)" and "print self" in pdb to give invaluable information in this case.

Comment: This isn't quite right: the base class `__init__` method assigns a `self.usage` *attribute* (not method). The right way to do what you want to do is not to subclass `ArgumentParser`, but to supply your own usage string when you instantiate: `myparser = ArgumentParser(..., usage="usage details here")`.

Comment: Interesting, but I know in my case I need to subclass ArgumentParser because I need to override the _error_ method. So in my case it works better to have a _myusage_ method called from _error_. But you make a very good point, and if I don't need my own _error_ method this is a better solution. Thanks!